# Is it possible to browse the file system and download files from my laptop to my Android phone using bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, files, transfer

Is it possible to browse the files on the computer and download specific files using Bluetooth?

I know already, of course, that I can download files from my laptop to my phone using Bluetooth.

But I want to have an experience similar to FTP, where I can browse every directory on the laptop from the smartphone, pick files and download to the phone using Bluetooth.

Is this possible and if so how?

Vesa

- Laptop: Ubuntu 16.04
- Mobile phone: Samsung Galaxy S5

Comment: Unfortunately Ubuntu 15.10 is no longer supported, please use a supported version of Ubuntu like 14.04, 16.04, or 17.04  I do think that Samsung does disable the browse over bluetooth feature on their newer phones

Comment: What are you talking about? I want to use the phone to browse the file system of the laptop using bluetooth, nothing else.

Comment: You can certainly do this over wifi (even a hotspot), but I'm not sure about Bluetooth.

Comment: @vesa I'm confused because in your edit, you've changed the version of Ubuntu from 15.10 to 16.04. You're right that the version is not important for this question, though if you're actually running 15.10, you should upgrade for your own sake.

Comment: Wjandrea, you are not answering the question. Please don't post here again and let somebody else try to answer if they can.